# std::string_view compile time hashing

Tags: c++, hash, std, c++17, string-view

It seems the [std::hash functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view/hash) for the C++17 string_view are not constexpr's.

It seems to me that a string view bound to a const char[] could be hashed at compile time (which would be very sweet), or is there anything which prevents this?

Comment: I don't think any of `hash<T>::operator()` is constexpr, even for integral types (or at least I can't find any mention of constexpr hash in n4567.)

Comment: Ah I see, didn't notice that, I wonder why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since C++14 (see 17.6.3.4 Hash requirements, table 26), we have:

> The value returned shall depend only on the argument k for the duration
> of the program. [Note: Thus all evaluations of the expression h(k) with
> the same value for k yield the same result **for a given execution of the
> program**. -- end note]

Two [different executions can give different hashes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the
> same input **within a single execution** of a program;
> this allows salted hashes that **prevent collision DoS attacks**.

[This behaviour is useful](http://lemire.me/blog/2014/04/23/do-you-realize-that-you-are-using-random-hashing/) to mitigate [hash collision-based DoS attacks](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html).

#### Details

Here's the wording about the requirements of the `Hash` concept from the C++17 standard:

> The value returned shall depend only on the argument k
> **for the duration of the program**. [ Note: Thus all
> evaluations of the expression h(k) with the same
> value for k yield the same result for
> a given execution of the program. — end note ]

It does not explicitly state anything about random hashing. The `std::hash` text does not mandate and does not preclude random hashing.

### History

Here's the [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) 2011-02-28 draft which did not mention “for the duration of the program”:

> Shall not throw exceptions. The value returned shall dependonly
> on the argument k. [Note: thus all evaluations of the expression h(k)
> with the same value for k yield the same result. — end note

We can see that the addition of "for the duration of the program" "for a given execution of the program" was added as a resolution for "[2291. `std::hash` is vulnerable to collision DoS attack](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2291)".

### In practice

AFAIU, no implementation of `std::hash` implements random hashing but you can write your own `my::secure_hash`.

Comment: Unluckily, the last sentence is not true at all. The standard indeed requires that the value depends only on the argument for a given execution of the program, that's right. However, that's because some implementations just cast pointers into hash values. Other implementations (e.g. GCC) demonstrably hash byte-wise at runtime using FNV1 with a built-in constant seed, so in practice there is no such thing as randomized hashing. So, the standard gives us the worst of two worlds: No predictable output value, no constexpr, and at the same time no _reliably_ non-predictable output value.

Comment: @Damon: I'd say it's not that bad. What the standard gives you is the ability to write you own `my::secure_hash` with non-predictable hashing and your own `my::fast_hash` with constexpr-ability. And it gives the ability for an implementation to use non-predictable hashing for `std::hash`.