# Why is std::hash not guaranteed to be deterministic?

Tags: c++, hash, language-lawyer, std

Hereafter, we use [N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) (C++14 Standard).

---

According to *§ 17.6.3.4 Hash requirements*,

> The value returned shall depend only on the argument `k`
>   **for the duration of the program**.
>
> [ Note: Thus all evaluations of the expression `h(k)` with the same value for
>   `k` yield the same result **for a given execution of the program**. — end note ]

and *§ 20.9.12 Class template hash* says

> ...
>
> the instantiation `hash<Key>` shall:
>
> (1.1) — satisfy the Hash requirements (17.6.3.4) ...
>
> (1.2) — ...

---

This means a hash value of `value` (i.e. `hash<decltype(value)>(value)`) may take a different value if you restart the program.

But why? This limitation was not in the Standard of C++11, but in the Standard of C++14, C++17 and C++20. As a user (not a STL developer), it would be quite useful if `std::hash` were deterministic. Are there any mathematical difficulties in implementing a deterministic hash function? But hash functions we daily use (e.g. deprecated `md5sum` or safer `sha256`) are all deterministic. Is there a problem of efficiency?

Comment: _"...Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program; __this allows salted hashes that prevent collision denial-of-service attacks__."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: It allows a deterministic algorithm to take non-deterministic inputs. Pointer values, for instance. An immutable data structure could hash the addresses of its internal data, which could be a lot faster than hashing the contents.

Comment: Note that implementations may give a stronger guarantee. You can't rely on the values changing, either.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917195/4342498) has some nice links in for why you would not want determinism.

Comment: Don't threat this as limitation, but making standard constraints a bit less strict.

Comment: Here is [full explanation why](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2291) constraints has been loosen up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no need for the hash function to be deterministic between runs, but you can still provide your own hash, e.g. for unordered containers if it's a behavior you rely on.

As for why, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) says:

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision denial-of-service attacks.

If the `Hash` requirements tells it to be deterministic, then you wouldn't be able to provide a salted hash without breaking the requirement.

Here is the [actual explanation why](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2291)

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917195/8776746) (and links in it) suggested by [@NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568162/why-is-stdhash-not-guaranteed-to-be-deterministic#comment107154995_60568162) is ultimately helpful. Let me cite important parts.

> For a non-cryptographic hash function, it's possible to pre-calculate massive inputs with the same hashed value to algorithmically slow down the unordered containers, and results in a denial-of-service attack.
>
> (from [*Issue 2291. std::hash is vulnerable to collision DoS attack*](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2291))
>
> For this reason, language designers are migrating to random hashing. In random hashing, the hash value of the string “a” can change every time you run your program. Random hashing is now the default in Python (as of version 3.3), Ruby (as of version 1.9) and Perl (as of version 5.18).
>
> (from [*Do you realize that you are using random hashing?*](https://lemire.me/blog/2014/04/23/do-you-realize-that-you-are-using-random-hashing/))

> Move to Ready, rather than Immediate, as even the permission has been contentious in reflector discussion
>
> (from [*Issue 2291. std::hash is vulnerable to collision DoS attack*](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2291))
>
> In practice, as far as I understand, no implementation of `std::hash` implements random hashing but you can write your own `my::secure_hash`.
>
> (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917195/8776746))

---

P.S.

I just googled "hash table dos" and found an informative page: [*The moment when you realize every server in the world is vulnerable*](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/hash-table-attack-8e4371fc5261/).